# How to declare a multidimensional array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to store details where the number of columns of array are fixed and number of rows are unknown.
I want to assign each column a key by extracting text from the div of a specific page and then assign the value to it.
This is my code

```
var data1=[[]];
var val=0;
$('.education_box.eb1 .inner_box').each(function(){
    $('.education_box.eb1 .inner_box ul li').each(function(){
        var key= $(this).children('strong').text();
        var value= $(this).children('em').text();
        data1[key][val]= value;
    });
    val++;
});
console.log(data1);
```

Please let me know how to declare the 2D array in line 1 as each time it gives the error: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Comment: See the given answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var data1= [];
for (var i=0;i<$('.education_box.eb1 .inner_box ul li').length;i++) {
   data1[i] = [];
}
```

then use:

```
 data1[key][val]= value;
```

Comment: where did you declare `data1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Declare array using `Array` class

```js
var data=[];

data[0]=new Array(10,2);;
data[1]=new Array("val1","val2");
data[2]=new Array(true,false);

console.log(data);
```